# automatically printing a vbhtml page without the print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-webpages

I have created a simple asp.net application that takes input from a user on a production line and then it needs to generate 5 barcodes and print them. I have the vbhtml pages that generate bar codes automatically when data is entered and inserted via the web page form. They open and display the barcodes.
I need them to print automatically when the page opens by skipping the print dialog and going straight to the default printer.

I have studied the JS window.print() and a couple JQuery Plugins, but I cant quite get my solution.

This will only be used on an internal corp network

Here is more info:
The barcodes will open in a web page for each code. Each barcode will print to a different size label. 
The label size is saved as a named layout in the printer and I would like to define a paper layout when I print.

Comment: I worked around a similar problem in a cross-browser way putting the labels (in my case) inside a pdf and embedding javascript into the pdf so it will print when opened - then if the browser opens PDFs by default (possible since it was on machines we controlled), forcing a download of the pdf resulted in it being printed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am considering this route too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are/can use Firefox there is a [plug in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/) which allows unattended printing without print dialog.

I have also read that you can do it in IE, but requires ActiveX, for example:

```
<script language=JScript>
function doprint() {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<object id='idWBPrint' width=0 height=0 classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>");
idWBPrint.ExecWB(6, -1);
idWBPrint.outerHTML = ""; }
</script>
```

Or similar in VBScript:

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
```

That Sub Print effectively replaces the default print function.  All you then need in Javascript is...

```
window.print();
```

There's also a [commercial product](http://scriptx.meadroid.com/about.aspx) that may help.

Comment: Thanks John, I added some more info to my post. The solutions you gave me look promising.